# ajax dropdown with clientside filtering capability

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, jquery

Can any one provide me an idea about any ajax control which has following capabilities:

1. User should able to type to get auto-suggestions
2. Dropdown should only display the values starting with the keyed-in characters.
3. Most importantly there should be only one postback to fetch all the data to client side on the first key-in and then should filter the list values based on rest of the keys.

Any ideas in this regard greatly appreciated..

Comment: Look into the Ajax Control Toolkit. It has something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this demo of the `Autocomplete` control in the `jQuery UI` library: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ The demo demonstrates all the features you need and provides source for it all.